# How to check if a certain date is passed

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have a string of the form "mm/yyyy" and I want to compare it against the date of the local system.

I have thought of either using a conversion table between my month and the MONTH field in Calendar, something like:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String date = "07/2014";
    String month = date.subString(0, 2);
    int monthToCompare;
    if (month.equals("01"))
      monthToCompare = cal.JANUARY;
    if (month.equals("02"))
      monthToCompare = cal.FEBRUARY;
    ...
```

And then comparing manually with an if. I don't like it because I think is way too long for such a simple operation.

The other option I've thought of is getting the current `Date()` and using the  `before()` method. That would mean translating my date to the Date format, but the easy methods to do it are deprecated, I must specify the number of milliseconds and I do not know how to easily do that (taking into consideration leap years, calendar corrections and so on since 1970).

Comment: I said I know about those two methods, and that I do not know how to create a Date object to compare with from a String.

Comment: Have you looked at [DateFormat.parse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String))?

Comment: Duplicate: [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4216745/642706)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Tip: `YearMonth` class.

Comment: Re-opening as I noticed the Question here is starts with only a year-month rather than a full date. Different from the duplicates we marked.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Using @Mifmif answer I finally solved the problem with:

```
if (new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy").parse(date).before(new Date())) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem in single line.

Answer (score 8):

Try this :

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy").parse("07/2014").compareTo(new Date());
```

Comment: It seems unlikely his goal is to know if it happens to be exactly midnight and zero milliseconds on the first of the month.....

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth.parse( 
    "07/2014" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/uuuu" )
).isAfter(
    YearMonth.now(
        ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )
    )
)
```

## java.time

The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes rather than the troublesome old date-time classes.

### Year & month only

To represent an entire month, use the `YearMonth` class.

```
String input = "07/2014" ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/uuuu" ) ;
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Tips: Use such `YearMonth` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere string. And when you *do* need a string to exchange data, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: `YYYY-MM`. The java.time classes use standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings, so no need to define formatting pattern.

### Current year-month

Determining the current year-month means determining the current date.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Same idea applies to getting the current `YearMonth`: pass a `ZoneId`.

```
YearMonth currentYearMonth = YearMonth.now( z ) ;
```

### Compare

Compare using methods `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `equals`.

```
boolean isAfterCurrentYearMonth = ym.isAfter( currentYearMonth ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
 //getting current date

private String getDateTime() {           

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());

    Date date = new Date();

    return dateFormat.format(date);
}


//compare the dates

Date date1  = new Date("second_date to be compared");

Date date2 = new Date(getDateTime());


if(date1.before(date2)) {

     Log.d("Date already passed", " " + "second_date");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: For me SimpleDateFormat with Date works great. I had very bad experience with Calendar. On some devices the dates where going crazy using Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following kotlin extension function for this.

```
/**
 * Checks if the string represents a date that is expired.
 *
 * This function parses the string as a date in the format "yyyy-MM-dd" using the UK locale,
 * then compares it to the current date. If the parsed date is before the current date,
 * it is considered expired.
 *
 * @return `true` if the string represents a date that is expired or if parsing fails,
 * `false` otherwise.
 */
fun String.isExpired(): Boolean {
    return try {
        val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.UK)
        // Return true if parsing fails (assuming expired)
        val parsedDate = format.parse(this) ?: return true
        parsedDate.before(Date())
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // Handle parsing exception (e.g., invalid date format)
        true  // Consider returning null or throwing a custom exception for specific handling
    }
}
```